# unable to figure out the concept of command line arguments in Java

Tags: java, command-line

```
public class CommandArgsThree 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        String [][] argCopy = new String[2][2];
        int x;
        argCopy[0] = args;
        x = argCopy[0].length;
        for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" " + argCopy[0][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

and the command-line invocation is:
 java CommandArgsThree 1 2 3

1.what is the difference between the above command and this: java CommandArgsThree 123,what is the args type and its behavior regarding the different inputs.

```
String [][] argCopy = new String[2][2];
```

2.does the above statement creates an two dimensional array of strings i.e it

```
null null
null null
```

as this can be accessed by argCopy[0][0],argCopy[0][1]
or

```
{null,null,null,null}
```

as this can be accessed by argCopy[0],argCopy[1],argCopy[2],,,,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the real misunderstanding here is regarding multi-dimensional arrays.

A 2 dimensional array is an array whose elements are references to 1 dimensional arrays.

When you initialize your array with

```
String [][] argCopy = new String[2][2];
```

you get an array that contains two arrays (rows), each having two elements (columns). The values of your array are all `null` by default.

When you assign

```
argCopy[0] = args;
```

The first row of your 2D array now refers to a different array than it originally referred to. Now the first row of `argCopy` contains 3 `String` elements (assuming you passed 3 parameters to the command line, as in `CommandArgsThree 1 2 3`), that can be accessed with `argCopy[0][0]`, `argCopy[0][1]` and `argCopy[0][2]`, and the second row still contains the original 2 null values.

When you pass a single parameter to the command line (as in `CommandArgsThree 123`), the `args` array contains a single `String` element, so after the assignment `argCopy[0] = args;`, the first row of `argCopy` contains 1 `String`.